# Flutter Web app takes more time to execute

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a existing plugin which supports Android and iOS. Now, i have tried to provide a web support. So, i followed the steps mentioned here,
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web
It takes more time to run the app in chrome.

In console of chrome, i could see following message.

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer_example/generated_plugin_registrant.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter_web_plugins/src/plugin_registry.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer_example/main.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer_web/src/web/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer_web.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/widgets/icon.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/src/control/scroll_head.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/material/colors.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer_web/src/web/resources/document_repository.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/material/app.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer_web/src/web/resources/page_repository.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/foundation/serialization.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/foundation/object.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/foundation/licenses.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_web.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/foundation/consolidate_response.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:53829/packages/flutter/src/foundation/print.dart.lib.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout

Flutter information:

> [√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.25.0-8.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.685], locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 1.25.0-8.1.pre at C:\flutter
> • Framework revision 8f89f6505b (3 weeks ago), 2020-12-15 15:07:52 -0800
> • Engine revision 92ae191c17
> • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-133.2.beta)

> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
> • Android SDK at C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
> • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
> • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
> ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

> [√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

> [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.31.0)
> • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
> • Flutter extension can be installed from:
> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

> [√] Connected device (1 available)
> • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 87.0.4280.88

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by replacing my reference packages from absolute path to hosted pub dev package reference in pubspec.yaml. Now, it takes few seconds to debug my flutter app.